# Caveats of scaling a Kafka cluster vertically vs horizontally?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are planning to build a multi TB Kafka Cluster.
From LinkedIn presentations, which are supposed to handle the largest Kafka cluster in the world, it seems like they are using a few pretty large servers.

We are planning to go the other way: Launch a lot of small Kafka brokers handling a few GB each.

What are the pros and cons of scaling vertically vs horizontally with Kafka? e.g for 50TB, having 5 brokers handling 10TB each, or 5000 brokers handling 10GB each.

Those numbers are made up.

ps: Maintaining 5 or 5000 servers for us has the same operational cost as it's all automated.

Comment: what were your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to go with 5 brokers with 10TB each, with 3 redundant copies of the data (RF3).  Kafka brokers generate a lot of crosstalk/chatter between them, so it's best to minimize the network overhead as well as operational and even cognitive overhead when there's issues.

You mention that operational cost is all the same to you.  In my experience, it's never that simple.  There's setup time, configuration for 5000 different machines, network traffic, etc. And even if it's all automated, 5000 servers will have hardware issues, on average, at 1000x the rate of 5 servers, so if you expect 1% of the servers to fail per year, you'll have brokers failing almost weekly.  Having large servers doesn't guarantee no hardware failures, but the likelihood is less.